# recursive function that goes through a built in list of numbers

Tags: python, recursion

need help with this question. Much appreciated.

Write a recursive function big_numbers that takes a Python built-in list of numbers and returns True if each number in the list is greater than 100 and False otherwise.

Comment: You should share what you think and where you are stuck instead of asking for someone else to write your program.

Comment: What you need exactly? Write an example. You wrote about the comparison. There is no recursion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def isGreater(myList, i=0):
    if(i == len(myList)): # Termination True case
        return True

    if myList[i] > 100:
        return isGreater(myList, i+1)
    else:
        return False # Termination False case
```

Demonstration:

```
test = [101, 129, 130]

print(isGreater(test))
```

> True

Comment: thank you! yeah i should have shared what I tried, sorry about that :)